# schedule task not working, log file with no errors

Tags: coldfusion, scheduled-tasks

I have a simple task schedule that sends a email for test.
It's not working at all,looking at the logs:

scheduler.log

```
Jul 8, 2016     1:20 PM     Information     scheduler-1      
[test] Executing at Fri Jul 08 13:20:00 PDT 2016
```

It shows that it has run, and I also think its not running other task.
Looking at the application log I also see no errors.

Is there any other place I should be looking at?

Comment: Look at the "sends a email for test" thing / setup and code. Does your code run and send email if you request using a browser?

Comment: @AlexBaban yes i test it on the browser

Comment: Can you show the code of the task to run?

Comment: You can look at the http log for a page request.

Answer (score 4):

The log you show above indicates if the scheduler ran if expected. It does not indicate if you page you ran was success.

To find out what happened with the page, go the the scheduled task editor and "Save output to a file".

Then specify a file name. Depending on the nature of the scheduled task, you may want to publish to a shared directory, or keep it hidden way.

Make sure to choose "Overwrite" so that you can always get the latest result of your scheduled task.

[image]